# Creating a button in excel to clear a field of data and save one previous row elsewhere in the document

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am new to this forum and just starting to learn programming. I had a question that hopefully will be useful to others as well. I have data saved in two columns and 30 rows that ends with a summation of each column at the bottom.

What I would like to do is create a VB program that saves the Sum, moves that value to a new row, and then clears all of the previous data so that it can be re-entered and again saved in a new location.

This program will be used to track emissions of vapor from a storage tank, monthly and as the data is entered each month I was hoping it could be saved specific to that month and then cleared and ready to enter the data into the next month. Thank you for any help or ideas you could provide.

This is the code I have come up with thus far,

```
Sub Macro4()
    Range("F15").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("C30:D30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C33").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C33").Select
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("C30:D30").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C33").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C28:D29").Select
    Range("D29").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C2:D29").Select
    Range("D29").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code to share (even if it doesn't work)? It's always easier to help if you can *be specific about what is preventing you from acheiving your goal*.  If you don't know where to start, try recording a macro while performing the steps you describe - take al ook at the code generated and see if you can modify it.  If you run into problems then post it here for suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tim, I used record macro and came up with this,Sub s()
'
' s Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Range("E31:F31").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=114
Range("C138").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection.Interior
.Pattern = xlSolid.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.Color = 5296274
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Range("E3:F30").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("E1").Select
End Sub

Comment: Sorry for the two reply's not enough characters in post, but I used that code, but I am having trouble figuring out how to relate that to a button, and then move to the successive row and not keep repetitively entering the new data into the same row. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any code - it's not readable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated with the recent version of the code that I have tried to modify with the button in my original question, let me know if there is any other way that I can clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (adjust ranges to suit)

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim rngDest as Range

    With ActiveSheet
       'find next empty row
        Set rngDest= .cells(rows.count,3).end(xlup).offset(1,0)

        'copy values
        rngDest.resize(1,2).value= .Range("C30:D30").Value    

        'clear input range
         .Range("C28:D29").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem - note I just edited my code: `offset(1,1)` should have been `offset(1,0)`